# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-redux-firebase

I got stacked with error for a while, I searched on the web all the answers I found on Stack Overflow and GitHub was related to updating React or correcting importing spelling, I did all of that but still Stacked.

Here is my Store

```
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import firebase from '../firebase/Firebase';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

// react-redux-firebase config
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
  attachAuthIsReady: true, // attaches auth is ready promise to store
};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig),
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase })),
    // for redux dev tools
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// store
import store from '../src/redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  // </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I found out the solution for this problem.
The problem is with the react-redux-firebase package, they've changed the way to initialize the package, here is the new code structure.

**The Store:**

```
 import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import firebase from '../firebase/Firebase';
import {  getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

// react-redux-firebase config
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
  attachAuthIsReady: true, // attaches auth is ready promise to store
};
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase })),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
const rrfProps = {
  firebase: firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  // createFirestoreInstance // <- needed if using firestore
};

export { store, rrfProps };
```

**Index js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from 'react-redux-firebase';

// store
import { store, rrfProps } from '../src/redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  // </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is where I found the solution [react-redux-firebase](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/)